# Adding a custom map marker icon to Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have done this dozens of times but today it seems it doesn't want to work. I have the following code, of which the map pin refuses to show?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.555555, -2.323702),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    }

    var image = 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/l/L/S/W/9/map-marker-hi.png';
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: 55.555555,
            lng: -2.323702
        },
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're creating the marker before you run your `initialize()` function which is used to create your map. Either include the marker creation in your `initialize()` function or change the order in which you are creating it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.555555, -2.323702),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

    var image = 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/l/L/S/W/9/map-marker-hi.png';
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 55.555555, lng: -2.323702},
      map: map,
      icon: image
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With [your code as posted](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6nn3a7Lh/), I get a javascript error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined`, because the `map` variable is local to the initialize function and your marker code is outside of that function.  Move the creation of the marker inside the `initialize` function.  (the marker is a little large also, so the code below scales it to a more reasonable size).

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.555555, -2.323702),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  // move inside initialize function
  var image = 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/l/L/S/W/9/map-marker-hi.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 55.555555,
      lng: -2.323702
    },
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: image,
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 32)
    }
  });
} // end of initialize
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```